# Ubuntu Core - Server + Nextcloud?

Tags: networking, server, hard-drive, samba, ubuntu-core

I have a question about Ubuntu Core. Somehow I managed to install Ubuntu Core 16 with Raspberry Pi 2 and install my own Nextcloud instance connected to the internet with a private Domain at home. I am not a technical expert therefore I am very proud.

Now, I want to use it as well as server for my home. The Raspberry Pi has 3 USB slots free and are perfect for 3 Hard Drives that are around our house for Files, BackUPs and Multimedia. My questions: is it possible with Ubuntu Core?

I have been looking and there is not information at all. So far, mount the Hard Drives is the easy part, but sharing (with PC Ubuntu OS, or Windows OS, MacOS) is missing. There is no "samba" Snap or anything similar to allow sharing and serving as a server.

Any idea how could I implement the sharing of Hard Drives (in an easy way and not destroying my Nextcloud instance) through Samba or any other tool out there?

Thank you!
Carlos V

Comment: Since NextCloud is already installed, can you use it for file sharing at home?

Comment: Not exactly. The HD has different capacities and purposes. Nextcloud has 2 TB, the HD have 3TB (not all fully used) and for different purposed. To use the current in the Nextcloud would mean I have to buy a HD with more than 8 TB to cover the current 3 HD. The other con is that Nextcloud is exposed to the Internet as a Cloud system. I want the servers to be reached only local network or via VPN (for security reasons).